# How to include DRF 3.8 router url patterns in Django 2.1

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-2.1

```
from app_listing import views
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'category', views.CategoryViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('router.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Here is the error while trying to include router.urls **,ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'.**

I am using Django2.1,DRF 3.8.2 and python 3.6. Tried a lot, but couldn't find a proper solution for this. Is this still an open issue ? Please help!.

Answer (score 7):

It should be just `router.urls` without quotes:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: oh, I missed it. Thought it was the same router url issue in the previous DRF versions. Thanks. Now it Works.